# Probability question a bag with $6$ black and $3$ white balls

Tags: probability, statistics

> From an bag with $6$ black and $3$ white balls, a ball is drawn (with re-laying) repeatedly until a black one is drawn. Let $Y$ denote the number of total number of draws. What is $P (Y = 1)$?

Is the correct way of thinking and answer:

$6/ 9 = 0,666667 = 67 \%$ because $p(y=1)$ means the probability of selecting a black on the first try?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to ask?

Comment: Equals signs are meant to be used only in the case of *equality*.  $67\% = \dfrac{67}{100}\neq \dfrac{66}{99}$.  Use `\approxeq` or `\approx` instead if you have to.  Better yet, don't try to write $\frac{2}{3}$ as a decimal expansion and instead leave it as a fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the balls in the bag are all equally likely to be chosen, yes, the probability is indeed equal to $2/3 \approx 67\%$, for the very reason that you have described.